# Unable to send mail on an ECS fargate job using python SDK with credentials of a verified SES in another aws account

Tags: python, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, amazon-ses, aws-fargate

I have a python app running in fargate ECS which sends emails. I have a verified SES in another account. I am trying to use these credentials in the python app , which runs in a different aws account than the verified SES. It uses the aws python sdk's ses module to create the boto3 ses object.
The mailing works if I create a boto3 ses object within the main app , without using the sdk. But when I use the sdk it seems to be using the SES in the main account (which is sandboxed) although I pass the verified SES account's endpoint, access and secret access keys  (these are stored as secure strings in my main account's parameter store).

What is the reason the sdk keeps using the main account's SES even if I supply it with credentials of the verified SES account? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That is because AWS Fargate also inject its own AWS environment into your container and it would be using the credential of the execution roles that you gave your tasks. So the hard coded environment will override your env's configuration.

The quickest solution is to name your SES's credentials differently in the parameter store. Go for something like

```
SERVER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your-key
SERVER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your-key
SERVER_AWS_REGION=your-region
```

instead of the conventional AWS credential declaration (Since it would be overridden)

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your-key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your-key
AWS_REGION=your-region
```

And then in your code, you would need to initiate a new instance of the aws-sdk using the `SERVER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `SERVER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and the `SERVER_AWS_REGION` that you have just saved.

Comment: The name in the paramstore is already different from the conventional aws cedential declaration. Creating a new instance of the sdk using these keys still does not solve the issue. The only way so far has been to create a boto3 object without the sdk in the main app. This means redundantly creating all required functions in the main app as well which is totally inefficient.

Comment: @DanielArvind There might be some places in your main app the sdk got override again. I'm not too familiar with Python to afford reading your code unfortunately. But my best bet would be to check the code where you create new instance of the SDK. Because what could have happen is that it was an async function and you were referencing an old instance of the SDK before the SDK was properly inject with new config.